# CTE with non-recursive and recursive in Mysql

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

I am not able to use 2 CTEs, first non-recursive and then recursive. However, I am able to run first recursive and then non-recursive.

How can we run this sequence of CTEs?

```
WITH simple_cte AS
        (SELECT 15 AS user_id ),
    
RECURSIVE recur_cte AS
        (SELECT 1 AS id
         UNION ALL
         SELECT id+1 from recur_cte WHERE id <=     
                                                (SELECT min(user_id) FROM simple_cte)
    )
SELECT * FROM recur_cte
```

Above is the sample code (actual use case is more complex).

[image]

Comment: You must use `WITH RECIRSIVE`. This means "some CTEs may be recursive" (not first but any of). Moreover, you may use this always - even when there is no recursive CTE. I.e. `RECURSIVE` is an attribute of WITH, not of a definite CTE.

Comment: With recursive does not work either

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=73c49116dca70556c1654a7d1bad8600 Maybe you use MySQL 5.x?

Comment: I am trying to run it in leetcode.

Comment: Leetcode needs to be on version 8 or above..try select version()

Comment: Version is 8.0.21

Comment: *Version is 8.0.21* The query shown in my fiddle must work on your version. If not then provide complete query text and error message.

Comment: @Akina 

select version() :

"headers": ["version()"], "values": [["8.0.21"]]}

I appended the error message in the question

Comment: If so then use the information mentioned in my first comment and look at my fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the given syntax

**CTE:** Temporary data set that can be used by another query. It begins with WITH keyword.

```
Syntax
-----------
WITH cte_name AS (cte_query_definition)
SELECT *
FROM   cte_name;
```

**Recursive CTE:** It is used to get hierarchical data.

```
Syntax
------------
WITH RECURSIVE cte_name 
AS (cte_query_definition (the anchor member)   UNION ALL    cte_query_definition (the recursive member))
SELECT *
FROM   cte_name;
```

Reference: https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-recursive-cte/